# Excel sheet loop command not working

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

```
Sub forEachWs()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Windows("XYZSheet.xlsx").Activate
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-2])"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/R1C5)"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D2:D2450").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Range("D2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
 Next Ws 
 End Sub
```

**The code does not loop through the other tabs within the Sheets of
   Workbook "XYZSheet.xlsx" and I cannot seem to understand why.**

The code in the middle from "Range(E1)" all the way to "ReplaceFormat:=False" are all through a recorded session with minor edits.

I don't fully understand VBA code apart from cycling through it with F8, so please go easy on me!

Thanks!

Comment: Was it in pasting? Your second line should be split into two at `.ActivateFor`, should be `.Activate`, then next line starts `For`...Also, I highly suggest reading through [how to avoid `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: think the for next should be on a new line

Comment: You are not activating the sheets in your `For` loop, so the loop always run on the same sheet. That is one of the main reasons why `.Select`should be avoided as @BruceWayne said.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
Sub forEachWs()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Windows("XYZSheet.xlsx").Activate
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(C[-2])"
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/R1C5)"
        .Range("D2").Copy Destination:=Range("D2:D2450")
        .Columns("D:D").Value = Columns("D:D").Value
        .Columns("D:D").Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    End With
Next Ws
End Sub
```